# Sort data frames with cost centres column and its user in user column Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have muliple dataframes from excel that I need to sort the data and merge it into one. I have cost centres that needs to match the user and the coresponding data.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Py_Projects\sample.xlsx')
>>> df1
  Department User           data         data.1  ... total2  option1  option2  option3
0         HR  wwe         sldkcm        ddkfjrw  ...     11      yes       a1      yes
1        Mng  ggt         qpodjc      asdpokqee  ...      8      yes       a1      yes
2         IT  ssd    qpwdjocnpio     q4-9r8jqf-  ...     42       no       a1      yes
3         HR  qqa     q3498qwdco     we9ddxzv[p  ...     67      yes       a2      yes
4         HR  wwe       q309f8q0   awefpqvqec0i  ...     11       no       a2      yes
5        Fin  wer       we095g8j   4ec-9jwoijsc  ...     21       no       a1       no
6        Fin  wer    qweprfj3-4f  23333013e09ic  ...     76       no       a2       no
7         WH  ddf  q3-49jqw-feij            NaN  ...     99      yes       a1      yes

[8 rows x 11 columns]
```

Df1 need to be added to the following Dateframe Df2 and then go over each row in df1 to see if user and cost centre are equal.

```
>>> df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Py_Projects\CostC.xlsx')
>>> df2
    Cost Centre User Department
0           100  wwe         HR
1           100  qqa         HR
2           100  dfg         HR
3           101  ssd         IT
4           101  ddh         IT
5           101  alk         IT
6           102  ggt        Mng
7           103  wer        Fin
8           103  jjk        Fin
9           103  pof        Fin
10          104  ddf         WH
```

I came close to concat but this adds df2 but the user column and cost centre doesnt show as equal.

```
>>> df2.set_index('User')
      Cost Centre Department
User                        
wwe           100         HR
qqa           100         HR
dfg           100         HR
ssd           101         IT
ddh           101         IT
alk           101         IT
ggt           102        Mng
wer           103        Fin
jjk           103        Fin
pof           103        Fin
ddf           104         WH
>>> 

>>> df1.set_index('User')
     Department           data         data.1  ... option1  option2  option3
User                                           ...                          
wwe          HR         sldkcm        ddkfjrw  ...     yes       a1      yes
ggt         Mng         qpodjc      asdpokqee  ...     yes       a1      yes
ssd          IT    qpwdjocnpio     q4-9r8jqf-  ...      no       a1      yes
qqa          HR     q3498qwdco     we9ddxzv[p  ...     yes       a2      yes
wwe          HR       q309f8q0   awefpqvqec0i  ...      no       a2      yes
wer         Fin       we095g8j   4ec-9jwoijsc  ...      no       a1       no
wer         Fin    qweprfj3-4f  23333013e09ic  ...      no       a2       no
ddf          WH  q3-49jqw-feij            NaN  ...     yes       a1      yes

[8 rows x 10 columns]
```

Now after concat

```
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
>>> df3
    Department User           data  ... Cost Centre User  Department
0           HR  wwe         sldkcm  ...         100  wwe          HR
1          Mng  ggt         qpodjc  ...         100  qqa          HR
2           IT  ssd    qpwdjocnpio  ...         100  dfg          HR
3           HR  qqa     q3498qwdco  ...         101  ssd          IT
4           HR  wwe       q309f8q0  ...         101  ddh          IT
5          Fin  wer       we095g8j  ...         101  alk          IT
6          Fin  wer    qweprfj3-4f  ...         102  ggt         Mng
7           WH  ddf  q3-49jqw-feij  ...         103  wer         Fin
8          NaN  NaN            NaN  ...         103  jjk         Fin
9          NaN  NaN            NaN  ...         103  pof         Fin
10         NaN  NaN            NaN  ...         104  ddf          WH

[11 rows x 14 columns]
```

This is my goal

```
>>> df4 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Py_Projects\Final Output.xlsx')
>>> df4
    Cost Centre User Department           data  ... total2 option1  option2  option3
0           100  wwe         HR         sldkcm  ...   11.0     yes       a1      yes
1           100  wwe         HR       q309f8q0  ...   11.0      no       a2      yes
2           100  qqa         HR     q3498qwdco  ...   67.0     yes       a2      yes
3           100  dfg         HR            NaN  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
4           101  ssd         IT    qpwdjocnpio  ...   42.0      no       a1      yes
5           101  ddh         IT            NaN  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
6           101  alk         IT            NaN  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
7           102  ggt        Mng         qpodjc  ...    8.0     yes       a1      yes
8           103  wer        Fin       we095g8j  ...   21.0      no       a1       no
9           103  wer        Fin    qweprfj3-4f  ...   76.0      no       a2       no
10          103  jjk        Fin            NaN  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
11          103  pof        Fin            NaN  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
12          104  ddf         WH  q3-49jqw-feij  ...   99.0     yes       a1      yes

[13 rows x 12 columns]
>>>
```

If someone can please point me in the right direction here. I am new to Pandas and have search but just cannot find the correct direction. This was my most recent try, I have tried pd.merge() and pd.join() as well but either get errors because the indexes are more than other dataframe or the columns just dont match up as it should in my example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pd.merge` and specify the type of join you want to do. Based on the desired output, it seems you want to do a outer join.

you can try something like this :

```
result = df2.merge(df1, how='outer',on = ['User','Department'])
```

if you are specifying the columns for `on` parameter, you don't need to set the `user` as the index for the dataframe.

you can read about merge [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Thank you. Works 100%. Do you recomend reading through the Pandas documentation from head to tail. I find it overwhelming at times.

Comment: I would suggest read the function, you are trying to use. Reading from head to tail is going to be overwhelming.